# Sprite Collision in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

How do I Make my powerup (a 2D sprite) destroy itself when the player (another 2D sprite) enters its trigger in unity?

I have them both on sorting layer 6 (On the sprite renderer). I'm not too sure what I've done wrong. Here is what I have on my powerup at the moment:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name == "Player")
    {
        Debug.Log("Collided");
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thats a trigger, but, do you have a collider? is it set to be a trigger on the powerup?? and thats a 3d trigger, not the 2d trigger.. you want OnTriggerEnter2D which takes a Collider2D

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the 2D version of the message https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html

Also, at least one of the objects needs a rigidbody component, if they don't have it already.

Otherwise it technically should work. There are better ways to check whether the collided object is a player, though. You're probably looking for something that's easy to setup and not too complicated, in which case I'd recommend giving it a [layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) (or a [tag](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html), but tags kinda suck because you can only have one - that's not really a tag in my opinion), and check for that instead of the name.

Oh, and finally, you don't need the `this` keyword in this context.